# Changing to Url-Form-Encoded Post Request in Swagger

Tags: post, swagger

I was wondering is it possible to create a url-form-encoded post request within Swagger? For example:

```
POST https://url.co.uk
Host: server.example.com
Authorization: Bearer <Initial Access Token>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

&grant_type=password
&client_id=<client id>
&client_secret=<client secret>
```

Currently we have the layout below for our various parameters but are not sure how to change to url-form-encoded. We have tried changing to`in:body`instead of header but this does not work. See example for grant-type parameter

```
          "parameters": [
                {
                    "in": "header",
                    "name": "grant_type",
                    "description": "Indicates that the app is using the Resource Owner Password \"password\".",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "password"
                        ] 
                },
```

Which currently returns this:

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6,sv;q=0.4
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: http://editor.swagger.io
Referer: http://editor.swagger.io/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 
grant_type: password
client_id: xxx-xxx-xxx
client_secret: <client_secret>
```

Any help/insight on this would be greatly appreciated - even to let me know if it is even possible?

Answer (score 12):

It's possible, you just need to set parameter's `in` value to `formData` as explained in in the OpenAPI (fka. Swagger) specification in the `Parameter` object [description](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameterObject):

> Used to describe the payload of an HTTP request when either application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data are used as the content type of the request (in OpenAPI's definition, the consumes property of an operation)

You can also read [part 5 section 1.7 of my OpenAPI specification tutorial](http://apihandyman.io/writing-openapi-swagger-specification-tutorial-part-5-advanced-input-and-output-modeling/)

Here's an example:

```
swagger: '2.0'

info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Form data API
  description: Using form data body parameters

paths:

  /examples:
    post:
      consumes:
        - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
      parameters:
        - name: grant_type
          type: string
          in: formData
        - name: client_id
          type: string
          in: formData
        - name: client_secret
          type: string
          in: formData
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
```

Answer (score 9):

For OpenAPI 3.0.X - The below example should help

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Sample Service
  description: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, recusabo gloriatur ius ne. 
  version: 1.0.0
tags:
  - name: tag1
    description: tag1 desc
paths:
  /test:
    post:
      tags:
        - tag1
      summary: generates token
      description: ''
      operationId: token
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                attr1:
                  type: string
                attr2:
                  type: string
                language:
                  type: string
                  default: en
                  enum:
                    - en
                    - es
              required:
                - language
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Sample response
        '400':
          description: Invalid response

externalDocs:
  url: 'https://github.com/'
  description: 'Additional info'
```

[When rendered the swagger looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjTaW.png)