# Open API/Swagger Symfony Annotations?

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, openapi, swagger-php

I'm trying to setup Open API 2 (fka swagger) using [swagger-php](https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php) but i haven't been able to find an example of a implementation using annotations with
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Only yaml examples, like the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436165/changing-to-url-form-encoded-post-request-in-swagger)

Taking from that example, if i have the endpoint

```
POST https://url.co.uk
Host: server.example.com
Authorization: Bearer <Initial Access Token>
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

&grant_type=password
&client_id=<client id>
&client_secret=<client secret>
```

How can this be expressed on Open Api **annotations** for a Symfony/PHP project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/2.x/Examples/petstore.swagger.io/controllers/PetController.php#L228

```
@SWG\Post(
    consumes={"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
    produces={"application/xml", "application/json"},
)
```

Or, if you currently use 3-d version, from https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/master/Examples/petstore.swagger.io/controllers/PetController.php#L241

```
@OA\RequestBody(
     *       required=false,
     *       @OA\MediaType(
     *           mediaType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
     *       )
     *   ),
```

Comment: This is what i needed. I don't know how I overlooked this on the github. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad I helped. Happy hacking ;)